# Why compiler doesn't allow std::string inside union?

Tags: c++

i want to use string inside Union.
if i write as below

```
union U
{
   int i;
   float f;
   string s;
};
```

Compiler gives error saying U::S has copy constructor.

I read some other post for alternate ways for solving this issue.
But i want to know why compiler doesn't allow this in the first place?

EDIT:  @KennyTM: In any union, if member is initialized others will have garbage values, if none is initialized all will have garbage values. I think, tagged union just provides some comfort to access valid values from Union. 
Your question: how do you or the compiler write a copy constructor for the union above without extra information?
     sizeof(string) gives 4 bytes. Based on this, compiler can compare other members sizes and allocate largest allocation(4bytes in our example). Internal string length doesn't matter because it will be stored in a seperate location. Let the string be of any length. All that Union has to know is invoking string class copy constructor with string parameter. In whichever way compiler finds that copy constructor has to be invoked in normal case, similar method as to be followed even when string is inside Union. So i am thinking compiler could do like, allocate 4 bytes. Then if any string is assigned to s, then string class will take care of allocation and copying of that string using its own allocator. So there is no chance of memory corruption as well.

Is string not existed at the time of Union developement in compiler ?
So the answer is not clear to me still.
Am a new joinee in this site, if anything wrong, pls excuse me.

Comment: Don't use `union` as you're new to C++, `union` is to fiddle with memory and that's a domain reserved to experts. You need to learn about object oriented C++ to understand why this happens and you lack too much concepts at the moment to understand any of the answer given (they might seem cryptic to you, truly). There are excellent resources available, and several topics on this site list them.

Comment: am new to this site, not to c++. Anyways.. Thank you all for your efforts and inputs.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Think about it. How does the compiler know what type is in the union?

It doesn't. The fundamental operation of a union is essentially a bitwise cast. Operations on values contained within unions are only safe when each type can essentially be filled with garbage. `std::string` can't, because that would result in memory corruption. Use `boost::variant` or `boost::any`.

Comment: @Matthieu: Pls check edited version of question.
According to me, it should not cause memory corruption.

Comment: @bjskishore: sizeof(string) is not portable. Also, the compiler can't find which constructor/etc to call because it doesn't know what type is in the union. All function calls must be known at compiletime or virtual, and a union is neither polymorphic nor compile-time constant. So the compiler can never know what to do. In addition, the size really, really doesn't matter- the problem is that it is a pointer. If you store a float in the union then access a string, you will have a binary float treated as a pointer, which will almost certainly point to invalid memory and crash your program.

Comment: @Puppy please fix the answer: the code OP asked for does work in C++11 and later.

Comment: @Hi-Angel I [tried it](https://godbolt.org/z/KsPvfP6a4) in a few different compilers using C++11 to C++20 but it wouldn't compile.  What compiler did you use?

Comment: @TedLyngmo sorry, I should've probably mentioned that it requires a little modification: adding an explicit constructor/destructor. [For example](https://godbolt.org/z/Kbhd4xjWT)

Comment: @Hi-Angel Yes, and then you need to keep track of which type it contains externally to be able to create/destroy the correct type, like in `boost::variant` (or nowadays, `std::variant`).

Comment: Right. Yeah, `std∷variant` these days is a much better alternative.

Answer (score 71):

Because having a class with a non-trivial (copy/)constructor in a union doesn't make sense. Suppose we have

```
union U {
  string x;
  vector<int> y;
};

U u;  // <--
```

If U was a struct, `u.x` and `u.y` would be initialized to an empty string and empty vector respectively. But members of a union share the same address. So, if `u.x` is initialized, `u.y` will contain invalid data, and so is the reverse. If both of them are not initialized then they cannot be used. In any case, having these data in a union cannot be handled easily, so C++98 chooses to deny this: (§9.5/1):

> An object of a class with a non-trivial constructor (12.1), a non-trivial copy constructor (12.8), a non-trivial destructor (12.4), or a non-trivial copy assignment operator (13.5.3, 12.8) cannot be a member of a union, nor can an array of such objects.

In C++0x this rule has been relaxed (§9.5/2):

> At most one non-static data member of a union may have a *brace-or-equal-initializer*. [*Note:* if any non-static data member of a union has a non-trivial default constructor (12.1), copy constructor (12.8), move constructor (12.8), copy assignment operator (12.8), move
>   assignment operator (12.8), or destructor (12.4), the corresponding member function of the union must be user-provided or it will be implicitly deleted (8.4.3) for the union. *— end note* ]

but it is still a not possible to create (correct) con/destructors for the union, e.g. how do you or the compiler write a copy constructor for the union above without extra information? To ensure which member of the union is active, you need a [tagged union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union), and you need to handle the construction and destruction manually e.g.

```
struct TU {
   int type;
   union {
     int i;
     float f;
     std::string s;
   } u;

   TU(const TU& tu) : type(tu.type) {
     switch (tu.type) {
       case TU_STRING: new(&u.s)(tu.u.s); break;
       case TU_INT:    u.i = tu.u.i;      break;
       case TU_FLOAT:  u.f = tu.u.f;      break;
     }
   }
   ~TU() {
     if (tu.type == TU_STRING)
       u.s.~string();
   }
   ...
};
```

But, as [@DeadMG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521914/why-compiler-doesnt-allow-stdstring-inside-union/3521972#3521972) has mentioned, this is already implemented as [`boost::variant`](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/variant.html) [or](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/variant/misc.html#variant.versus-any) [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/any.html).

Comment: What is the definition of trivial or non-trivial constructors?

Comment: @SiverSun trivial are those that the compiler creates for you, non-trivial those that you code. @KennyTM, great answer indeed!

Comment: @KennyTM: Pls check the edited question as i am unable to add more text as part of comment.

Comment: @bjs: Maybe you should ask a new question. (Basically, the string needs to allocate some memory from the heap, ...)

Comment: WorksForMe in c++11.

Comment: How exactly do you use boost::any or boost::variant to cast from vector<int> to string?

Answer (score 16):

In C++98/03, members of a union can't have constructors, destructors, virtual member functions, or base classes.

So basically, you can only use built-in data types, or [PODs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure)

Note that it is changing in C++0x: [Unrestricted unions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Unrestricted_unions)

```
union {
    int z;
    double w;
    string s;  // Illegal in C++98, legal in C++0x.
};
```

Answer (score 8):

From the C++ spec §9.5.1:

> *An object of a class with a non-trivial constructor, a non-trivial copy constructor, a non-trivial destructor, or a non-trivial copy assignment operator cannot be a member of a union.*

The reason for this rule is that the compiler will never know which of the destructors/constructors call, since it never really knows which of the possible objects is inside the union.

Answer (score 1):

The garbage is introduced if you

1. assign a string
2. then assign an int or float
3. then a string again

string manages memory somewhere else. This information is most likely some pointer. This pointer is garbaged when assigning the int. Assigning a new string should destroy the old string, which is not possible.

The second step should destroy the string, but does not know, if there has been a string.

They obviously have found a solution for this problem in the meantime.

Comment: This question is over 5 years old. An answer now should really also deal with the changes that where made in C++11 and how `std::string` [could be a member of a union now](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union). Maybe some example code would be a good idea.

Comment: Some people are stucked with old versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can now do it.
Of course if you initialize any other member of the union first, or simply don't initialize the string at all, then there's a problem.
Since the string class overloads the assignment operator, you can't then initialize the string with an assignment operation:

```
this->union_string = std::string("whatever");
```

Will fail because you're still using the assignment operator.

To properly initialize a union string after you've put something else in the union or not initialized it in the first place, you have to call the constructor directly on that memory:

```
new(&this->union_string) std::string("whatever");
```

This way you're simply not using the assignment function at all.

Another concern is your compiler should make you make a destructor, and if for some reason not, you should make it anyway. Since it's a union, by the end of your class's lifetime the compiler can't know whether that union memory is used by the string or something else, so your destructor should call the string's destructor if that's the case.
So if you don't do it, you'll have a memory leak since the constructor for the string is never called, and it never knows to release the memory it's using.

Answer (score 0):

In new C++ standard (I tested it in C++17), you can use a complex type as a member of union.

```
    struct ustring
    {
        union
        {
            string s;
            wstring ws;
        };

        bool bAscii = true;
        ~ustring()
        {
            if (bAscii)
            {
                s.~string();
            }
            else
            {
                ws.~wstring();
            }
        }
    };
```

However, you should be very careful. Think about you construct s but destruct ws.