# Why is std::string incompatible with C unions?

Tags: c++, string, unions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why compiler doesn't allow std::string inside union ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521914/why-compiler-doesnt-allow-stdstring-inside-union)

I knew that I had this problem when I started with C++: The compiler wouldn't allow me to put a variable of the type `std::string` into unions.

That was years ago, but actually I still don't know the exact answer. I read something related to a copy function with the string that the union didn't like, but that's pretty much all.

- Why are C++ STL strings incompatible with unions?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521914/why-compiler-doesnt-allow-stdstring-inside-union

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(computer_science)#C.2FC.2B.2B):

> C++ does not allow for a data member to be any type that has a full fledged constructor/destructor 
>   and/or copy constructor, or a non-trivial copy assignment operator. In particular, it is impossible to 
>   have the standard C++ string as a member of a union.

Think about it this way: If you have a union of a class type like `std::string` and a primitive type (let's say a `long`), how would the compiler know when you are using the class type (in which case the constructor/destructor will need to be called) and when you are using the simple type?  That's why full-fledged class types are not allowed as members of a union.

Answer (score 4):

Class which have user-defined constructor or user-defined destructor is not allowed in `union`.

You can have *pointer* of such class as member of union, though.

```
struct X
{
   X() {}
   ~X() {}
};

union A
{
   X x; // not allowed - X has constructor (and destructor too)
   X *px; //allowed!
};
```

Or you can use [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/variant.html) which *is a safe, generic, stack-based discriminated union container*.

§9.5/1 says (formatting and emphasize is mine)

- A union can have member functions (including constructors and destructors), but not virtual (10.3) functions.
- A union shall not have base classes.
- A union shall not be used as a base class.
- An object of a class with a **non-trivial constructor** (12.1), a **non-trivial copy constructor** (12.8), a **non-trivial destructor** (12.4), or a **non-trivial copy assignment** operator (13.5.3, 12.8) **cannot be a member** of a union, nor can an array of such objects.
- If a union contains a *static* data member, or a member of reference type, the program is *ill-formed*.

Interesting!

Comment: Is this a definite workaround? This answer seems overlooked and I'd really like to know more. What are the disadvantages/worries/issues with using pointers in a union, if any?

Comment: @sunday: Yes. Or you can use `boost::variant`.