# Shared ptr in union

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, unions

I want to access shared ptr, which is in union, though segmentation fault happens:

```
struct union_tmp
{
    union_tmp()
    {}
    ~union_tmp()
    {}
    union
    {
        int a;
        std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> ptr;
    };
};

int main()
{
    union_tmp b;
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> tmp(new std::vector<int>);
    b.ptr = tmp; //here segmentation fault happens
    return 0;
}
```

What is the reason of an error and how can I avoid it?

Comment: That code does not produce a segfault

Comment: @Rerito:  That code exhibits undefined behaviour.  *Anything* can happen.

Comment: What are your actually trying to achieve here?  A union of an int ansd a shared_ptr is a rather strange beast.  This feels like it may be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @MartinBonner I encountered the problem, when I was writing a _small_ _number_ _optimization_ for my big integer class for long arithmetics. My big integer class contains a vector, which stores big number by base 2^32. The idea is not to store a vector, but to store such union, so the memory will not be allocated if the value of big integer is less, than 2^32. I use shared pointer, not usual one, to add also _copy-on-write optimization_ later.

Comment: OK.  That's an entirely reasonable usage :-) (Although personally, I would want to use `uintmax_t` rather than `int` - but it doesn't change the example).  Presumably you currently have a flag elsewhere to indicate what the union holds.  I would use `std::variant`, and let it hold the flag.

Comment: Also, beware CoW - it has bad characteristics in a multi-threaded environment (which is why I believe CoW is now outlawed for `std::string`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to initialize the `std::shared_ptr` inside the union:

```
union_tmp()
: ptr{} // <--
{}
```

Otherwise, `ptr` remains uninitialized, and calling its assignment operator triggers undefined behaviour.

Comment: Probably worth adding a comment that the reason for the error is that `b.ptr = tmp` calls the shared_ptr copy assignment operator, and that assumes that the shared_ptr is already properly initialized.

Comment: @MartinBonner I guess being explicit doesn't hurt.

Comment: I think marking this as answer is wrong. The OP's code is invalid C++ code as he is violating the restrictions that the standard puts on unions.

Comment: @Mr.C64 what do you mean ? This is valid, as long as care is taken to initialize the correct member.

Comment: @Mr.C64 are you referring to switching active members of union? It looks like one can not switch between `int` and `shared_ptr` easily.

Comment: @Mr.C64 these restrictions have been lifted in C++11.

Comment: @Quentin: Interesting! I didn't know that.

Comment: This answer explains it http://stackoverflow.com/a/3521998/649322
But I agree with MrC64, `variant` is better.

Answer (score 7):

I would use [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) for safe C++ *"unions"* (or `boost::variant` if `std::variant` is not available for you).

E.g. you may try:

```
std::variant<int, std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>>> v;
v = std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>();
```

Comment: I'm not sure about if it's valid to use class with those things as a member, there's an example showing how to use `std::string` and `std::vector` to be the members of union. It seems it's valid, but very tedious. Please correct any of my mistake, thanks. Read here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union

Comment: @MarsonMao: I still think variant is better (safer, higher level, less error/bug prone).

Comment: I agree, this answer has the same aspect as you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3521998/649322