# C++ unions with string types

Tags: c++

Reading [cppreference.com's page on Unions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union), an example is presented as below:

```
union S
{
    std::string str;
    std::vector<int> vec;
    ~S() {} // needs to know which member is active, only possible in union-like class 
};          // the whole union occupies max(sizeof(string), sizeof(vector<int>))
```

The motivation for [`boost::variant`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/variant.html#variant.motivation.problem) presents that it is illegal to have a `std::string` in a `union` and so does the answer to an SO question [why-compiler-doesnt-allow-stdstring-inside-union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521914/why-compiler-doesnt-allow-stdstring-inside-union).

Which one is right? and why does the code in the cpp-reference work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read *all* the answers on the [old] Q&A you linked, not just one.

[kennytm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3521998/560648) explains that the rule was relaxed in C++11, and gives an example.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to understand the motiviation behind `boost::variant` really.

Comment: @SamerTufail Bear in mind that _Boost.Variant_ predates C++11 by a lot.

Comment: The answer doesn't say that boost variant works like this. It says that boost variant is an existing implementation of tagged union. It is actually not implemented using a `union` at all.

Comment: @eerorika Granted (and fixed) Thanks!