# union is gives an error with string datatype but works with char datatype

Tags: c++, unions

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


union f 
{
    string car;
    int model;
};

int main(){
  union f p;
  p.car = "mclaren";
  cout<<endl<<"car :"<<p.car<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

"string car;" gives an error an something like this " is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:".

but when i replaced the string with a char it showed no error. is this becuase unions dont work with string datatypes or there is some other reason?

Comment: @brc-dd It does works with non-trivial types since C++11 if only you provide a constructor/destrutor, and control their lifetime on your own.

Comment: While it's _possible_ to use non-trivial types in unions, you probably shouldn't.  Prefer `std::variant<std::string, int>` instead.  That will automatically manage the lifetime of the contained object.

Comment: `std::variant` is specific to C++17 or above. If you're not on that standard, you may need to handle the cons/destruction manually. This answer shows how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3521998/11613622

Comment: If you're on C++17 or above then you may also consider using `std::any`.

Comment: You are missing include string

Answer (score 0):

Since the std::string is non-POD, you will have to define a constructor/destructor to make it work for c++11 and above.