# Multiple data types of Linked List nodes in class C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, generics, struct

I want to create a Node in Linked List, with data has multiple type (ex: int, string).

So the first thing right in my mind is template.

`header file`

```
template <typename T>
class SymbolTable
{
  struct Node
  {
    string id;
    T data;
    Node *next;
  };
 
public:
  void insert(string id, string dataType); // I intend to use "dataType" to deduce type of data in Node struct
}
```

`cpp file`

```
template<typename T>
void SymbolTable<T>::insert(string id, string dataType)
{
  Node *traverser = &(this->head);
  while (traverser->next != nullptr) // Insert at the end of Linked List
  {
    traverser = traverser->next;
  }

  Node *newNode = new Node();
  newNode->id = id;
  newNode->next = nullptr;
  traverser->next = newNode;

  // I don't know how to use "dataType" to deduce the type of data in Node struct
}
```

But then in `main.cpp`, it said

```
SymbolTable *st = new SymbolTable(); // cannot deduce class template arguments <-- I don't want this
```

So is there anyway to

1. Deduce the type of data using a variable + condition (something like: if dataType == "number" then deduce T -> int) in `cpp file`?
2. Get rid of "cannot deduce class template arguments" in `main.cpp`?

P/S:

- No external library except `string`
- File in `main.cpp` can't be modified

Comment: Right now, you've written a class template. `SymbolData<int>` is one instantiation of this template, which will contain `int`s. `SymbolData<std::string>` will be a different instantiation, and its nodes will contain `std::string`s. Are you trying to make a data structure where a single `SymbolTable` can hold multiple different nodes, each with different data types?

Comment: @NathanPierson Yes

Comment: You should look at `std::variant` it has the ability to hold a set of predefined types or if that does not work look `std::any`

Comment: Are std::variant, std::any in external library (that I have to included). I forgot to write in my post that I can use only <string> lib

Comment: You could implement `std::variant` or `std::any` by yourself, but it's complicated. Are you sure that you need to store multiple data types in `SymbolTable`? Maybe you could only store strings and use `dataType` to interpret the string later?

Comment: That is my plan B @TimRakowski.

Still it's good to know if my idea can become true or not :)

Also, thanks for your idea

Comment: Fully reimplementing `std::variant` would be quite a bit of work, but if you only need a very specific set of possible types then you could "hardcode" them as a tagged union (there are some examples e.g.: on cppreference https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union)

Comment: @UnholySheep Unfortunately, union don't allow string type https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521914/why-compiler-doesnt-allow-stdstring-inside-union

Comment: It does since C++11 - are you using an older standard?

Comment: Modern C++ allows complex types in `union`s, but you have to do some really fiddly of work to make them function correctly. Somebody has to construct and destroy the `string` when the active member of the `union` changes to or from the `string`. Usually not worth it, in my opinion, as there's almost always a better solution that'll work without the `union`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to do something like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct Node
{
     string id;
     T data;
     Node *next;
};

template <typename T>
class SymbolTable
{
public:
    void insert(string id, T dataType);

private:
    Node<T> *root = nullptr;
}

SymbolTable<string> table;
table.insert("hello", "My data");
```

I'm not actually coding it, but this might work.