# Union with shared ptr (constructor, destructor)

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, destructor, unions, construct

```
struct B {
 int b;
}
struct D {
 int * d;
}

class A {
 union {
   B part1;
   D part3;
 } parts;

public:
 A() {
    memset(&parts, 0, sizeof(parts));
 }
```

Now i want rewrite struct D in this way:

```
struct D {
 std::shared_ptr<int> d = nullptr;
}
```

How should I rewrite constructor and destructor of class A to store it in a vector and use functions as `emplace_back()` which needs default constructor?

Comment: If you write `std::variant<B,D>` instead, you have to rewrite exactly nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why compiler doesn't allow std::string inside union?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521914/why-compiler-doesnt-allow-stdstring-inside-union)

Answer (score 1):

Use [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) insted:

```
struct B { 
  int b;
};

struct D {
  std::shared_ptr<int> d;
};

struct A {
  std::variant<B, D> parts;
};
```